# Applescript to parse terminal

Tags: applescript

I am trying to create an apple script that alerts me every time a key word is returned in terminal (I have a program that runs in terminal and returns a lot of data). In my case I use iTerm instead of terminal, but it's the same idea.

So if the word "any" is returned in iTerm, I would like the result to be "found any".

The code below is returning Result: {"found %s", {"any", "of", "these", "words"}}

```
application "iTerm"
set found to ["any", "of", "these", "words"]
if the found exists then
    return {"found %s", found}
end if
```

Comment: *key word is returned* from what?

Comment: Basically I have a program that runs in the background in the terminal, and returns a lot of data, mostly I don't need to look at this data. But there are a few key words that the program could throw that I would want to give immediate attention to. So I want an alert set on specific words that might show up in the terminal.

Comment: Can't you handle the cases **in** the *program* ?

Comment: @vadian Valid point. But I'm not a very good programmer and a) I don't want to break the working program I have, and b) applescript looked easier.

Comment: If you call a bash script directly from AppleScript then you can process the result. If you run a bash script which periodically prints out something to `stdout` or `stderr` you can't due to its asynchronous behavior.